# How to access Shared Preferences in FirebaseMessaging background and FirebaseMessaging.onMessage

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to get values from Shared Preferences when I will receive anything in bakckground with `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {}` .

I have tried to access it but it does not give any value from shared pref.

How to get it?

Comment: Not working when app is in backgroun

Comment: Do you mean FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen  ?

Answer (score 0):

Force refresh in order to avoid empty instance of Shared Preferences.

```
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.reload();
  final Int? soundVolume = prefs.getInt('sound_volume');
  print(soundVolume);
});
```

Reference: https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/reload.html

Comment: Not working when application in background or in recent